# PHP mySQL Variable mismatch &nbsp; and space issues

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have an options value drop down and a switch to set the drop down. I am pulling the values from the mySQL server and trying to match the value to a value in the switch to set the drop down value.

```
echo $attribute;
$attributeArray =  array("","Hello World");
$attribute2Array =  array("","Hello World");
switch ((string)$attribute) {
case "$attribute2Array[1]":
    $attributeArray[1] = "selected";
    break;
}
echo "
<br>Attribute:<form method=post action=attributeEdit.php>
<select name=attribute>
<option value=$attribute2Array[0] $attributeArray[0]>$attribute2Array[0]</option>
<option value=$attribute2Array[1] $attributeArray[1]>$attribute2Array[1]</option>
</select></br> 
 ";
```

The echo says the exact same thing as the switch does at least in the chrome web browser. So I have tried to replace the space in "Hello World" with "Hello&nb sp;World" (no space in the nb sp) but I cannot seem to get this to work. I have tried casting replacing and print_r etc. I have tried a if boolean comparison and it returns false. My method works except for values with spaces in them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
echo $attribute;
$attributeArray =  array("","Hello World");
$attribute2Array =  array("","Hello World");
$attribute3Array =  array("","Hello-World");
switch ((string)$attribute) {
case "$attribute2Array[1]":
    $attributeArray[1] = "selected";
    break;
}
echo "
<br>Attribute:<form method=post action=attributeEdit.php>
<select name=attribute>
<option value=$attribute2Array[0] $attributeArray[0]>$attribute3Array[0]</option>
<option value=$attribute2Array[1] $attributeArray[1]>$attribute3Array[1]</option>
</select></br> 
 ";
```

Instead I just created a new array and switched against it with "-" instead of spaces show the space form on the webpage. The dashed values were saved in mySQL. Thanks anyways

Comment: Please read my answer. Just once, it will only take you a moment.

Answer (score 0):

The space breaks the "value" as it's not a *string* contained in quotes.

You are generating the HTML:

```
<option value=hello world selected>hello world</option>
```

How will the browser know that "world" goes with "hello"?

```
<option value="hello world" selected>hello world</option>
```

Note the colour formatting here intepreted this in much the same way the browser would, with "hello" being blue and anything after that not being associated with "value". Whereas the second example, the whole value is blue as intended.

Technically in HTML, only integer values were allowed to be without quotes around them. Now-a-days people put quotes around all values for any HTML attribute.

p.s. A cleaner way of writing that multi-line block, allowing you to be sure PHP isn't being interpreted as strings:

```
echo <<<EOT
    <html attribute="{$phpvariable}">
EOT;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

edit: You have posted another broken version as an "answer", please accept this answer and delete yours as it suffers from the same error but you've just hidden the problem. The only reason yours works now is because hello-world is a single word.